# Trying to compile all scss files into one css file

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

I have a grunt file but I am having problems getting it to compile.  When I watch it it appears to run fine but does not produce any files.

What am I missing?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pngmin: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    ext: '.png',
                    force: true,
                    speed: 3,
                    colors: 200
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true, // required option
                    src: ['**/*.png'],
                    cwd: 'public/images/src/', // required option
                    dest: 'public/images/dist/'
                }]
            }
        },
        sass: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: "public/sass",
                        src: ["**/*.sass"],
                        dest: "public/stylesheets",
                        ext: ".css"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '**/*.scss',
                tasks: ['sass']
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-pngmin');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['pngmin', 'watch', 'sass']);

};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are watching *scss* files, but you have *sass* files in your **sass** task.

Assuming you are using *sass* files, you have to change your code to something like this:

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: "public/sass",
                    src: ["**/*.sass"],
                    dest: "public/stylesheets",
                    ext: ".css"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: '**/*.sass',
            tasks: ['sass']
        }
    }
```

Regards.